# Как хранить в БД многомерный массив?

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server, entity-framework

Правильный ли подход для хранения такой конструкции в базе данных?

```
public class Series
{
    public int[][] Groups { get; set; }
}
```

Данный класс должен хранить несколько групп значений:

```
// в качестве примера без использования БД [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
int[][] groups = { new [] { 1, 2 }, new [] { 3, 4 } };
```

Получилось следующее (связь `многие-ко-многим` если правильно понял):

```
public class Offset
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Offset> Offsets { get; set; }
}

public class Series
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class ManyToManyEF : DbContext
{
    public ManyToManyEF()
        : base("name=ManyToManyEF")
    { }
    public virtual DbSet<Offset> Offsets { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Series> Series { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (ManyToManyEF db = new ManyToManyEF())
    {
        Offset[] offsets = new Offset[4]
        {
            new Offset() {Value = 1},
            new Offset() {Value = 2},
            new Offset() {Value = 3},
            new Offset() {Value = 4}
        };
        db.Offsets.AddRange(offsets);

        Group[] groups = new Group[2]
        {
            new Group() {Offsets = offsets.Take(2).ToArray()},
            new Group() {Offsets = offsets.Skip(2).Take(2).ToArray()}
        };
        db.Groups.AddRange(groups);

        Series series = new Series() {Groups = groups};
        db.Series.Add(series);

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ответ зависит от того, что собственно надо делать с этим массивом. Одно дело, если надо просто загрузить на сервер весь массив или извлечь весь массив. Другое - если надо извлекать определённые срезы с массива. Третье - если надо средствами SQL обрабатывать этот массив. Уточните задачу.

Comment: @Akina массив будет загружен в базу единожды и будет только читаться из него. Читаться полностью. А потом нужно будет пробегать по каждой группе значений и проверять их по определенным условиям.

Comment: Ну если он грузится исключительно целиком, а потом считывается опять же целиком (вероятно, в такой же массив?), и обрабатывается только на клиенте в виде того же массива - наверное, проще всего сразу весь массив как объект загружать в BLOB (используя штатные средства сериализации ЯП) и соответственно таким же манером выгружать оттуда.